# building my own rosjava android package doesn't work

Tags: ros, package, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to create my own rosjava android package. For this, I use the instructions on [click](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build). It works fine as long as I don't add the dependency "srs_decision_making":

```
<package>
  <description brief="my_package">

     my_package

  </description>
  <author>Ubuntu</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/my_package</url>

  <depend package="rosjava"/>
  <depend package="android_gingerbread"/>
  <depend package="srs_decision_making"/>

</package>
```

When doing the "rosmake my_package" I'll get a build error saying:

**package org.ros.message.std_msgs does not exist**

However, this java package can be found in ~/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.std_msgs-0.0.0.jar

Any idea, why it says, it can't find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12662/building-my-own-rosjava-android-package-doesn%27t-work/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried adding a dependency on std_msgs to your manifest? It probably shouldn't be necessary. But, if adding the dependency fixes things, you may have found a bug.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-01-31**:
Interesting. I filed an issue, feel free to star it. http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=82

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-01-30**:
It seems to be some sort of bug, I think. I posted it on http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rosjava-package-not-compilable-when-messages-includes-as-dependency-td3669216.html.